# How can I put data in Google Chart using AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to create a Google area chart in model using AJAX. If I use the response from the AJAX request then the Google Chart doesn't work. If I use default values, then it works. Where is the problem? Thanks in advance.

```js
function showDetails(REPORTNO, date1, date2, locid, cancelId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "catdetail.php",
    method: "POST",
    async: true,
    data: {
      "REPORTNO": REPORTNO,
      "date1": date1,
      "date2": date2,
      "locid": locid,
      "cancelId": cancelId
    },
    success: function(response) {
      var qty = "";
      details = JSON.parse(response);
      $.each(details, function(i) {
        res = details[i];
        timeord = res[0];
        catqty = res[1];
        qty += "['" + timeord + "'," + catqty + "],";
      })
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        alert(qty);
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Time', 'Qty'],
          //['1', 12],['2', 12],['3', 12],['4', 12],['5', 12]
          qty
        ]);
        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Category Sales by Time',
            titleTextStyle: {
              color: '#333'
            }
          },
          vAxis: {
            minValue: 0
          },
          pointSize: 18,
          pointShape: {
            type: 'star',
            sides: 5,
            dent: 0.5
          }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_detail'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<div id="chart_detail" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: Compare the data sets between default and your custom dataset and see the difference

Comment: Can we get an example of the AJAX response?

Comment: Ajax response same like this ... ['1', 12],['2', 12],['3', 12],['4', 12],['5', 12] ...When I make qty in alert

Answer (score 0):

since you're sending an array in json format,
you do not need to rebuild the array on the client.

you only need to add the column headings. (which could probably be done in php as well)

```
  success: function(response) {

    var details = JSON.parse(response);
    details.ushift(['Time', 'Qty']);
```

then use `details` to create the data table.

```
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(details);
```

see following snippet...

```
function showDetails(REPORTNO, date1, date2, locid, cancelId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "catdetail.php",
    method: "POST",
    async: true,
    data: {
      "REPORTNO": REPORTNO,
      "date1": date1,
      "date2": date2,
      "locid": locid,
      "cancelId": cancelId
    },
    success: function(response) {
      var details = JSON.parse(response);
      details.ushift(['Time', 'Qty']);

      google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ['corechart']
      }).then(function () {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(details);
        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Category Sales by Time',
            titleTextStyle: {
              color: '#333'
            }
          },
          vAxis: {
            minValue: 0
          },
          pointSize: 18,
          pointShape: {
            type: 'star',
            sides: 5,
            dent: 0.5
          }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_detail'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Its show me error Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid row type for row 0

Comment: and you  added the column headings? --> `details.ushift(['Time', 'Qty']);` -- will you please edit the question with the latest code?